# ALT Key Shortcuts Hidden

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts, winforms

I am using VS2008 and creating forms. By default, the underscore of the character in a textbox when using an ampersand is not shown when I run the application.

ex.   "&Goto Here" is not underlining the G until I press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key.

Is there a way to have this underline the text that I put an ampersand in front of when the form/application starts instead of having to have the user press the alt key?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it feasible to emulate the ALT key being pressed when the form loads then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a desktop setting in Windows.

Right click the desktop, go to Properties, then click the Appearance tab, and then click the Effects button. You should see the setting for *"Hide underlined letters for keyboard navigation until I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key"*

There are similar settings for Vista and 7 that you can set.

These are, however, individual desktop settings (and this one, sadly, is the Windows installation default).

Comment: It is called "Hide underlined letters for keyboard navigation until I press the Alt Key".

Answer (score 1):

''''''''''''' its working fine

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load      
  Dim myThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf SendAltKey)
  Call myThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub SendAltKey()
  System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%")
  System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("Esc")
End Sub
```