# Is there a way to remove Alt-character shortcuts from controls at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a dialog with a number of Alt-Letter shortcuts on labels for textboxes/etc.  This dialog can present data in either an editable or a read-only mode.  I've received a request to hide the underlines for the shortcuts if the dialog is in read only mode.  Other than editing the label text at runtime (ugh) is there any way to remove them?

If you don't know what I'm referring to by alt-Letter shortcuts see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701815/alt-key-shortcuts-hidden) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just iterate the controls and remove the ampersands.  For example:

```
public partial class dlgSample : Form {
    public dlgSample(bool isReadOnly) {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (isReadOnly) ZapMnemonics(this.Controls);
    }

    private void ZapMnemonics(Control.ControlCollection ctls) {
        foreach (Control ctl in ctls) {
            if (ctl is Label || ctl is Button) ctl.Text = ctl.Text.Replace("&", "");
            ZapMnemonics(ctl.Controls);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the problem isn't removing them, it's putting them *back* afterward.

Comment: @Jon S: That's only a problem if the dialog can change from Read Only to Edit mode without being recreated. If so, he could keep a list of the original labels. Clumsy though.

Comment: @nobugz  Thanks but the last thing I want is to give myself CM problems the first time I forget to make the same change to both dialogs.

Comment: What the heck is a "CM problem"?  What change?  It's just a bit of code.

Comment: @Jon Seigel  There aren't any cases where I'd need to restore them, I was just hoping for a less ugly looking implementation than recursively walking the Controls property to hunt down and stomp on each label individually.

Comment: @nobugz I believe this implementation will also zap actual & which are used as display characters and not Mnenonics

Comment: @nobugs CM = Configuration Management.  If I created MyDialogEditable and MyDialogReadOnly, then every time I had to change the data displayed I'd need to remember to make the change in two places.  It's copy/paste code at the class level.

Comment: @Dan: you missed the point: this is ONE dialog that does both.  Note the constructor argument.  Use it as a base class of your real dialogs, if you have to.

Comment: @nobugz  Sorry, I got confused and thought your "recreate the dialog" comment was a suggestion for an alternate implementation approach, not simply a reply to Jon S.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the value of the `UseMnemonic` property, then the ampersand shows up in the label, so I'm not sure how you're going to be able to remove the underlines without changing the label.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `KeyPreview` property of the form to `true` and then add a handler for the form's `KeyDown` event.  If the keypress is one of the shortcut keys then set the `Handled` property of the `KeyEventArgs` parameter to `true`.  Or you can set the `.SuppressKeyPress` property of the `KeyEventArgs` variable to `true`.

You can check the `.Alt` property of the `KeyEventArgs` variable to make sure the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed at the same time.